# How to exclude JS script from the bundle when building app with vite?

Tags: vuejs3, vite, rollupjs

Due to [another issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72530354/unable-to-load-external-component-script-with-vue3-using-vite), I have to import a JS dependency statically in HTML in my vue3 application.

**`/index.html`**

```html
<head>
    <!-- ... -->
    <script type="module" src="node_modules/@telekom/scale-components-neutral/dist/scale-components/scale-components.esm.js"></script>
</head>
```

As Vite cannot properly bundle this dependency (due to an issue, see the post mentioned above), I would like the bundling to ignore it. In the production build, I want the JS module to be imported as-is in the root `index.html`.

I tried pretty much everything in `optimizeDeps.exclude` config property, but Vite still tries to analyze and pre-bundle it.

**`vite.config.ts`**

```js
export default defineConfig({
  optimizeDeps: {
    exclude: [
      // I tried pretty much everything here: no way to force vite pre-bundling to ignore it...
      'scale-components-neutral'
      '@telekom/scale-components-neutral'
      '@telekom/scale-components-neutral/**/*'
      '@telekom/scale-components-neutral/**/*.js'
      'node_modules/@telekom/scale-components-neutral/**/*.js'
    ],
  },
  // ...
});
```

In every case, after running `npm run build`, the import has been removed from `dist/index.html`.

What does `optimizeDeps.exclude` config expect?

---

**Edit**

Following this note, found in https://vitejs.dev/guide/dep-pre-bundling.html:

> Dependency **pre-bundling only applies in development mode**, and uses esbuild to convert dependencies to ESM. In production builds, @rollup/plugin-commonjs is used instead.

I tried to specify `build.commonjsOptions.exclude` config.

**`vite.config.js`**

```js
export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    commonjsOptions: {
      exclude: [
        'scale-components-neutral',
        'node_modules/@telekom/scale-components-neutral',
        'node_modules/@telekom/scale-components-neutral/**/*',
        'node_modules/@telekom/scale-components-neutral/**/*.js',
        '/node_modules/@telekom/scale-components-neutral',
        '/node_modules/@telekom/scale-components-neutral/**/*',
        '/node_modules/@telekom/scale-components-neutral/**/*.js',
        '**/node_modules/@telekom/scale-components-neutral',
        '**/node_modules/@telekom/scale-components-neutral/**/*',
        '**/node_modules/@telekom/scale-components-neutral/**/*.js',
        '@telekom/scale-components-neutral',
        '@telekom/scale-components-neutral/**/*',
        '@telekom/scale-components-neutral/**/*.js',
        '**/node_modules/@telekom/scale-components-neutral/dist/scale-components/scale-components.esm.js',
      ],
    },
  },
  // ...
```

No more success: the import stills disappears from `dist/index.html`.

---

**Edit 2**

[`build.rollupOptions.external`](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#external) and [`build.dynamicImportVarsOptions.exclude`](https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/dynamic-import-vars#exclude) were promising (as the initial issue concerns dynamic imports...).

But no more luck there: the JS dependency is still ill-bundled. It works in local dev but not on a deployed app built with `npm run build`.

Comment: Vite only pre-bundling on development. So the normal import (from `node_modules`) instead of adding the module directly to `index.html` should work on the production build.

Comment: I can't have one version of code to use in dev mode, then change it before building for prod. I need a solution that work for both.

Comment: Please check my comment on your first question

Comment: May find a workaround using this: [How can I exclude a vue folder from being build in vite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69531394/how-can-i-exclude-a-vue-folder-from-being-build-in-vite)

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? I'm facing the same issue rn

Comment: Sorry, no. Instead, I fixed the reason I could not bundle the dependency with Vite (it was a Stencil issue, fixed by Stencil since). Good luck...

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I needed to exclude some assets that were nested within a node_modules dependency which otherwise was ok to be bundled. This config worked:

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      external: /@patternfly\/elements\/pf-icon\/icons\/.*/,
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    react(),
  ],
});
```

The key difference here was that I needed to use a RegExp object, not a glob string, to specify the children of the package which I wanted to exclude.

Comment: That works. { external: 'package-name' }

Answer (score 1):

To answer your generic question, you could use [vite-plugin-external](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-plugin-external) to tell `vite` to get `stuff` in

```js
import { stuff } from 'xyz'
```

from `window.XYZ.stuff`.

**Usage:**

```js
import createExternal from 'vite-plugin-external';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    createExternal({
      externals: {
        xyz: 'XYZ'
      }
    }),
    vue()
  ]
});
```

---

But it doesn't seem necessary in your case. To use ScaleComponents in a vite4 + vue3 app:

**main.js:**

```js
import { createApp } from "vue";
import "@telekom/scale-components/dist/scale-components/scale-components.css";
import {
  applyPolyfills,
  defineCustomElements,
} from "@telekom/scale-components/loader";
import App from "./App.vue";

applyPolyfills().then(() => {
  defineCustomElements(window);
});

const app = createApp(App);
app.config.compilerOptions.isCustomElement = (tag) => tag.startsWith("scale-");
app.mount("#app");
```

Now you can use `<scale-*>` components in your app.

---

Alternatively, you could use `vite.config.js` to declare the customElements:

```js
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';

export default {
  plugins: [
    vue({
      template: {
        compilerOptions: {
          isCustomElement: (tag) => tag.startsWith('scale-')
        }
      }
    })
  ]
};
```

... and simplify mounting the app to:

```js
createApp(App).mount("#app")
```

[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/vue3-vite-forked-1egmdb?file=%2Findex.html)

Comment: I know how to use scale. But, in my situation at the time I posted the question, Vite could not bundle correctly this dependency. So my question was "how to exclude a dependency from the bundle and just load the JS version as-is, as a separate script ?". The particular case of Scale was just an example. I will have a look at vite-plugin-external, see if it meets the need.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds from your comment of how you eventually resolved the issue was that the issue you were having wasn't actually in the bundling itself, but in the transform that vite was performing on the plugin.

To separate a dependency from the bundle, you can use the `rollup`'s `output.manualChunks`. [Rollup docs](https://rollupjs.org/configuration-options/#output-manualchunks)

Example:

```js
//vite.config.js
...
export default defineConfig({
...
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      output: {
        manualChunks: { lodash: ['lodash'] }
      }
    }
  }
})
```