# Excluding JS scripts when building app with vite - is there a solution?

Tags: vue.js, vite

This question [has been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72542395/how-to-exclude-js-script-from-the-bundle-when-building-app-with-vite) but there appears to be no concrete answer. My situation is perhaps simpler, and perhaps someone has found a solution by now.

I'm using vite to build a vue.js app, and wish to exclude a bunch of .js files which are just data (word lists for a word game) and which will be modified over time by the server. The files are in a  subdirectory of the main build. I have added them into index.html:

```
<body>
<script  type="module" src="./src/assets/words/3letter.js"></script>
  ......
<script type="module" src="./src/assets/words/9letter.js"></script>
<div id="app" align="center">
</div>
<script type="module" src="/src/main.js"></script>
```

and after reading through several posts here and at github I have modified `vite.config.js` in various ways:

```
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
    }
  },
  optimizeDeps: {
    exclude: [
      './src/assets/words/*.js'
    ],
  },
  // build: {
  //   commonjsOptions: {
  //     exclude: [
  //       './src/assets/words/*.js'
  //     ]
  //   }, 
  // }
})
```

but neither the `optimizeDeps` method or the `commonjsOptions` method works; when I run `npm run build` the word files are still included in the build, and the refs to them are removed from index.html

If I remove `type="module"` from the html refs, the build process gives me errors:

> script src="./src/assets/words/3letter.js" in "/index.html" can't be bundled without type="module" attribute

and the relevant lines aren't removed from `index.html`, but the word lists are still being bundled! - they're easy to see inside the big resulting built .js file

Answer (score 0):

I guess I was taking the wrong approach.
Since the .js files I want to excllde are just data (which my change over time)....

```
export const words4 = [
"ABED",
"ABET",
"ABLE",
"ABLY",
"ABUT",
"ACED",
....]
```

.....it's best that I recreate them as .json files instead of .js files, then use an http GET to retrieve them. Or, since MySql will be running on the server, store the words lists there.