# Export web-component with Vaadin and exclude shared elements

Tags: spring-boot, vaadin, vite

I'm using Vaadin's `WebComponentExporter` to export a Vaadin view as a web-component. The export works and I can see the JavaScript at `http://localhost:8080/web-component/my-vaadin-view.js`. But when I try to embed this web-component in another Vaadin app, I get an error:

```
caught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'define' on 'CustomElementRegistry': the name "vaadin-big-decimal-field" has already been used with this registry
    at window.customElements.define (http://localhost:8080/languages/Kotlin:6:829)
    at http://localhost:8081/VAADIN/generated/jar-resources/vaadin-big-decimal-field.js:74:20
```

According to [this](https://github.com/Artur-/iot) example project (made by Vaadin), this is a commons issue and can be solved by introducing a "bundle":

> Web components can only be defined once in the browser. ... To deal with this, the bundle module includes all used components and all other application modules excludes all components in their webpack config. ...

But how can I build this with Vite? Vaadin is not using Webpack anymore.

Comment: Are you effectively asking this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72542395/how-to-exclude-js-script-from-the-bundle-when-building-app-with-vite